# How to make a trigger that fires on the last weekend day every month

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Is there any way to make a trigger that fires on the last weekend day every month using quartz scheduler?

Comment: but how to write cron expression

Comment: http://v1.corenominal.org/howto-setup-a-crontab-file/

Comment: check out [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) it's a lifesaver

Answer (score 1):

The Quartz Scheduler supports this with the 'L' character.

As an example, to run at 9:30am on the last day of every month the cron expression is:

```
0 30 9 L * ?
```

Comment: Last day != Last weekend